# Prove that if $S ⊆ T$, then $S = T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$ and let $S, T $and $U$ be subspaces of $V$ such that
$\dim(S\cap U) = \dim(T\cap U)$ and $\dim(S+U) = \dim(T+U)$. Prove that if $S \subseteq T$, then $S = T$.

From the second dimension formula we get:
$\dim(S)+\dim(T)=\dim(S+T)+\dim(S\cap T)$ and if $S \subseteq T$ it means that $S\cap T=S$. So $\dim(T)=\dim(S+T)$.
And I don't know what to do from here. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Presumably $V$ (or at least $S, T, U$) are finite dimensional.

Comment: Apply the dimension formula for $T+U$ and $S+U$ and show that $\dim S=\dim T$